# Why 404 error comes if I click on allure report link on my Jenkins page

Tags: jenkins, allure

I believe that I have successfully integrated jenkins with allure report. When I build the project it runs the test cases and creates a allure report link on the page but when I click on this link it redirects to the following url-
"http://{hostName}/job/{projectName}/{buildId}/allure/" and this page shows the 404-page not found error.

Kindly suggest if I am missing some configuration or I need to put the jenkins jar in my project folder?

Comment: The answer is here-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020269/jenkins-not-able-to-identify-the-correct-directory-for-the-generated-allure-repo

Comment: Am getting same error when clicked on Allure Report on Jenkins. Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

Well faced the same error. Mine fixed with a port configuration in Configure System. Default 8080 was busy so Jenkins works on 8083. But the parameter Jenkins URL was set on 8080. Changed it to 8083 and allure works fine.